# a place for network connection checking

Tags: java, android

I've got a simple hiearachy of activities where: A is abstract and B,C, etc inherit from A.
I need a place to handle network connection and it would be good to place it in the parent activity(A). However, I don't see how I can stop code in my child activities(B,C) from executing. Additionally, in each of the onResume methods of the child activities(B,C) I have extra network code which shouldn't be executed as well.

So, is there any way apart from "if" in parent onCreate + "if" in child onCreate + "if" in child onResume ? This approach should be more concise.

Comment: In what way do you want to handle the network connection? Are you looking to detect certain network states? I am really not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I'm with WindyB - I also don't understand what's being asked here.

Comment: Why don't you make the network check a static method in a utility class and call it just before you do a network request? It's certianly possible that the network switches after resume and before you make the network call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep a boolean in abstract activity A like isNetworkAvliable. check network existence in Oncreate of A or onResume of A ( must call super.onResume in B and C before all work) and put the network in if(isNetworkAvliable).

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

1. Even if B and C are inherited from A, i dont think the methods for handling network will be
   executed in B and C until you explicitly call them.
2. And if you want to handle the network connection in class A, then create a method in 
   class A as `public void handleConnection()`, then make calls from class B's and C's 
   `onCreate()` and `onResume()` as `super.handleConnection();`